# cppcheck : possible null point dereference

Tags: c++, cppcheck

My below code is working properly but still "cppcheck" is giving warning,

```
Either the condition 'mem_limit_str!=0' is redundant or there is possible null pointer dereference: mem_limit_str.
```

Below is the code,

```
 if (mem_limit_str!= NULL) //CPPCHECK error
                free(mem_limit_str);
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: You can `free(NULL)`, so the check is useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to check for a null pointer before `free`ing. You can simply say:

```
free(mem_limit_str);  // no if condition
```

This warning just tells that the `if` condition is redundant.

From [n1124](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) draft

> **7.20.3.2 The free function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h> 
> void free(void *ptr);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be
>   deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is
>   a null pointer, no action occurs. [...]

Comment: Then what if mem_limit_str is pointing to NULL, i will get segmentation fault, right?

Comment: Ok Tried Thank you. I thought freeing NULL is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free) could be used with null pointer well. The check is redundant.

> If ptr is a null pointer, the function does nothing.

BTW: It's true for `delete` and `delete[]` too.

Comment: @Chirag BTW, it's same for `delete` and `delete[]` too, in c++.